# How can i fix Multi-level Side Nav Menu mouse hover issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to expand the menu is jumping to the left and right parts. I have added my javascript code HTML and CSS below for your reference hope you can find my issue from the below code. Please make sure you going to use mouse hover after expanding my menu then only you can find the problem what i am facing

```
[URL of issue][1]
```

This issue mainly I am facing when I expand also how can I make a popup menu instead of this drop-down menu?

attached my concept for the popup menu screenshot for ref.here is the screenshot of popup menu that i am looking

Comment: Sorry i dont know why my URL not showing in my comment
you can find the issue URL here https://codepen.io/sanoobdesign/pen/qBRXmjQ

Answer (score 0):

The menu "jump to the left and right" because of the `hover` listener. You have just to add a variable that holds the menu state (`true` means that menu has already been open) and when it's called the listener on `hover` you check the value of this variable and do the stuff in the callback only when the it is `false`

```
var alreadyOpen = false

$('.nav-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    alreadyOpen = !alreadyOpen;
  $("html").toggleClass("openNav");
  $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");

});

$('.menu').hover(function(){
    if (!alreadyOpen) {
        $("html").toggleClass("openNav");
        $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution its worked for me.............